# Homotopy type of $S^2 \times S^1$ with a collapsed $S^1$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Consider the quotient space $S^2 \times S^1/\{pt\} \times S^1$, where $\{pt\}$ is a fixed point on $S^2$. Can we show that the quotient space is homotopy equivalent to $S^2 \vee S^3$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space you describe is homotopy equivalent to $S^2 \wedge (S^1 \sqcup \{*\})=S^2 \wedge (S^1 \vee S^0)$ where the basepoint of $S^1 \vee S^0$ is the wedge point. This homotopy equivalence comes from the fact that the original expression is homeomorphic to $S^2 \wedge (S^1 \vee S^0)$ where the basepoint of the latter is the disconnected point (so this portion is not actually a wedge of $S^1$ and $S^0$ because it has the wrong basepoint). These two different basepoint choices become equivalent as long as we contract a line segment between them in the smash product. Since smash products distribute over wedge products we have $(S^2 \wedge S^1 ) \vee (S^2 \wedge S^0)=S^3 \vee S^2$.